# Spotify: How to embed a trackset with the new API?

Tags: spotify

What used to work:

```
<iframe width="500" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"
src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:trackset:My personal two tracks:1Lzzo2Ps2ivKxEKDyID4IO,3Qy9NQz8XuOhPqefJobvhd">
</iframe>
```

This rendered as an embeded player with a custom **set** of tracks **without** creating a playlist (and embedding that). Now this opens a new tab showing "Sorry, couldn't find that." and returning a 404 Not Found. [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DdLaz/2/) (not mine) to show the issue.

My question: Is there currently a way to embed multiple tracks without the need to create a playlist? I am aware of the docs saying [how to get information for multiple tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-several-tracks/) and the docs explaining [how to embed a single item](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/) (one track, one playlist, ...), but how do I combine those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracksets have been removed from the Spotify Play Button. As seen on the website (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/):

> Deprecation of tracksets: Please note that we have deprecated the
>   support for tracksets in the Spotify Play Button and will be removed
>   on July 15th 2017.
>
> We recommend that you use Spotify Play Buttons for playlists instead.
>   You can create playlists dynamically using our Web API and get the
>   benefits of being fully integrated with all Spotify clients. This
>   means users will be able to search for your playlists and subscribe to
>   them.

So to answer your question - no, there is no way to embed multiple tracks (that aren't an album, etc) without creating a playlist.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But #1: It's May 23rd, so it should work until July 15th, there must be something else wrong. But #2: Just because "the support for tracksets in the Spotify Play Button [...] will be removed" _might_ mean there's no other way to do this, but I would not conclude that from this quote _alone_

Comment: Hm: But I guess since you have an "Engineer at Spotify" in your description, I guess I can conclude it from that :-D Thanks

Comment: Please note my (previously working) example code's `src` startet with `https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=`, not with `https://open.spotify.com/embed?uri=`, so I'm not even sure I use(d) the Play Button...

Comment: Yes, tracksets have been removed.

Comment: embed.spotify is also the Spotify Play Button.